# spring-boot:build-image behind a proxy

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven, containers

I'm trying to follow building a docker image with spring boot 2.3.0 from behind a proxy.

According to the docs https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.0.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#build-image-example-builder-configuration I need something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <env>
        <HTTP_PROXY>http://proxy.example.com</HTTP_PROXY>
        <HTTPS_PROXY>https://proxy.example.com</HTTPS_PROXY>
      </env>
    </image>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I couldn't get that to work. However I could get it to work when prefixing the variables with BPL_ like below

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <env>
        <BPL_HTTP_PROXY>http://proxy.example.com</BPL_HTTP_PROXY>
        <BPL_HTTPS_PROXY>https://proxy.example.com</BPL_HTTPS_PROXY>
      </env>
    </image>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

So it this a bug, or something that I don't understand.

Even better, could this be specified outside the pom like from command line? I'm using powershell.

Comment: I had same problem, however looks like that feature comes with version 2.4, not with version 2.3

Comment: You can read here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image-example-builder-configuration . I Tested it with 2.4.3 and it works.

Comment: Thank you @jim-sellers, I have been running into `Get "https://github.com/bell-sw/Liberica/releases/download/11.0.13+8/bellsoft-jre11.0.13+8-linux-amd64.tar.gz": dial tcp 140.82.112.4:443: connect: connection timed out` and couldn't figure out where to configure the proxy. Your first example using `<configuration><image><env><HTTP_PROXY/><HTTPS_PROXY/></env></image></configuration>` finally did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there, according to https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.5.6/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.examples.builder-configuration  use `HTTP_PROXY`

```
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
        <image>
          <env>
            <HTTP_PROXY>http://some.proxy:3011</HTTP_PROXY>
            <HTTPS_PROXY>http://some.proxy:3011</HTTPS_PROXY>
          </env>
        </image>
 </configuration>
```

If you have the proxy is on your host and you want the build pack to use it, you can set `<HTTP_PROXY>http://host.docker.internal:3011</HTTP_PROXY>` and `<HTTPS_PROXY>http://host.docker.internal:3011</HTTPS_PROXY>` the `host.docker.internal` is the ip of the host machine for commands that are running inside the container